# Create and write to excel file through crm's javascript event that calls to webservice

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

now i know that it has been problematic in the past, and i got the common error 
"could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
and i know there is no prob in the webservice but from crm it pops up

tnx for the helper

Comment: Is Excel installed on the machine executing the code?

Comment: No, and i cant install it there, but is there some way to do it with openxml ?

Answer (score 0):

if the Excel file is on the server, where the WebService is hosted, you should not have a problem. Just make sure that the *server* has the Excel Installed!